# fit.resid gives error 'Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead'?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics, statsmodels

Below is the dataframe:

```
   CNSSSBDVSN     CNSSSBDVS1                CNMCRGNNM  \
0     5941833      Kluskus 1                  Cariboo   
1     5949832        Iskut 6  North Coast / Cote-nord   
2     5941016      Cariboo H                  Cariboo   
3     5955040  Peace River B     Northeast / Nord-est   
4     5941801  Alkali Lake 1                  Cariboo   

                         CNSSSBDVS3  instagram_posts  airports  \
0                    Indian Reserve                0         0   
1                    Indian Reserve                0         0   
2  Regional District Electoral Area                0         0   
3  Regional District Electoral Area                1        17   
4                    Indian Reserve                0         0   

   railway_stations  accommodations  visitor_centers  festivals  \
0                 0               0                0          0   
1                 0               0                0          0   
2                 0               5                0          0   
3                11               0                0          0   
4                 0               0                0          0   

   ports_and_ferry_terminals  attractions  
0                          0            0  
1                          0            0  
2                          0            0  
3                          0            0  
4                          0            0
```

Below are the code. before you read it, two points I would like to mention: 1. I believe something went wrong with the residual or indexing
2. CNSSSBDVSN can be used as indices if needed

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats as stats

from tabulate import tabulate


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Read data
    census_subdivision_without_lower_mainland_and_van_island = pd.read_csv('../data/augmented/census_subdivision_without_lower_mainland_and_van_island.csv')

    # Select data
    cities = census_subdivision_without_lower_mainland_and_van_island[census_subdivision_without_lower_mainland_and_van_island['CNSSSBDVS3'] == 'City']
    non_cities = census_subdivision_without_lower_mainland_and_van_island[census_subdivision_without_lower_mainland_and_van_island['CNSSSBDVS3'] != 'City']

    # Fit
    fit_cities = sm.ols(formula="instagram_posts ~ airports + railway_stations + ports_and_ferry_terminals + accommodations + visitor_centers + festivals  + attractions", data=cities).fit()
    fit_non_cities = sm.ols(formula="instagram_posts ~ airports + railway_stations + ports_and_ferry_terminals + accommodations + visitor_centers + festivals  + attractions", data=non_cities).fit()

    print(fit_cities.summary())
    print(fit_non_cities.summary())

    # Residual
    cities['residual'] = fit_cities.resid
    non_cities['residual'] = fit_non_cities.resid
```

gives error:

```
/Users/Chu/Documents/dssg/done/linear_model_cities.py:27: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  cities['residual'] = fit_cities.resid
/Users/Chu/Documents/dssg/done/linear_model_cities.py:28: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  non_cities['residual'] = fit_non_cities.resid
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that cities is a slice of census_subdivision_without_lower_mainland_and_van_island
if you want to use cities as its own dataframe from here on you can just create a copy with:

```
cities = census_subdivision_without_lower_mainland_and_van_island[census_subdivision_without_lower_mainland_and_van_island['CNSSSBDVS3'] == 'City'].copy()
```

Alternatively if you wish to modify the original dataframe you can insert the results using loc as the error mentioned:

```
census_subdivision_without_lower_mainland_and_van_island.loc[census_subdivision_without_lower_mainland_and_van_island['CNSSSBDVS3'] == 'City','residuals'] = fit_cities.resid
```

And similarly for the non-cities. As an fyi, I'd use shorter dataframe names in order to keep your code readable and within recommended python line limits

Comment: Yes, essentially, it defines a slice of the index, but the slice is still pointing to the original dataframe and so the warning is trying to prevent you accidentally modifying the original. That's way making a copy or explicitly modifying the original works.